# E-commerce database with many products approach

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I want to create an e-commerce website using Wordpress and Woocommerce (these are the demands). The products I want to import are a lot, close to 30k. Every product is being described by a main category and 4 subcategories and every category has different attributes. The dataset I was given is a csv with all the information in there. I don't really want to be too specific, neither I want to share part of my data cause it is confidencial. My first thought was to clean the dataset and import it in my own custom schema with multiple tables that would make info extraction easy. This would also help because importing new data in a custom schema is easier (as far as I know) and faster than importing with woocommerce and I can bridge that schema with erp software maybe later on. How someone would approach this problem so I won't have to do workarounds in the future if company decides to evolve their system? Thanks in advance

Comment: Without anything very specific it will be hard to answer your question. All I know that it will be virtually impossible to anticipate all future developments, and create an approach now that will smoothen all future import paths. This is basically what you're asking. Changing demands on a system will always involve a lot of work.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thanks for the answer. I know it's hard and sorry for not providing enough information, but I really can't. Ok, I get the part where system updates will need a lot of  work but what I really want to know now is should I create my custom schema or should I go with woocommerce? What approach from these two would make my life easier if i want to bridge that database in the future?

Comment: Most go with woocommerce (WC), because it is an existing system with lots of options. Developing something similar to that yourself is a lot of work. Any changes to a system you make yourself also entails a lot of work, and making just one wrong design decision can make evolving the system virtually impossible. If you choose an eco-system like WC you're limited by what it can do, but most changes are easy. I run several webshops for which I have designed everything myself, and I often get request for connecting to API's of third parties, which is a lot of work. With WC it's just a plugin.

Comment: Basically the whole industry expects you to use something like WooCommerce, and they don't expect you to create your own platform.

Answer (score -1):

There's a reason there's a knife labeled explicitly as a steak knife in your drawer. They can be either straight-edge blades or serrated edge blades and look similar to others, but steak knives are designed to cut through steaks easily instead of forcing you to hack away at them.

The right knife can decrease frustration at the dinner table and help you get more out of a meal while leaving your beef cut only where you want it to be.

Comment: Please don't add unrelated answer